# How to I get the scrollbar on the VerticalLayout rather than the HorizontalLayout in Vaadin Flow

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin23

This is using the [Vaadin starter project Hello World example](https://start.vaadin.com/app). In essence I want to have the scrollbar in the `VerticalLayout` on the left rather than on the whole page as shown in the image below:

[image]

However no matter what I do the scrollbar always appears on the right side. I suspect this may have to do with the `AppLayout` but I'm not sure how to adjust it so that the scrollbar is on the `VerticalLayout` shown in the diagram below.

The code is as follows:

```
add(getHelloVerticalLayout(), new HorizontalLayout(new Button("Simple")));
```

Where `getHelloVerticalLayout()` consists of just a bunch of Hello buttons so that it's large enough to generate a scrollbar on the webpage.

```
private VerticalLayout getHelloVerticalLayout() {
    List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int x=0; x<=50; x++)
        buttons.add(new Button("Hello"));
    return new VerticalLayout(buttons.toArray(Button[]::new));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your layout, which needs a scrollbar, with the Scroller component. See the official docs for more information and example https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/scroller

Comment: Yes, use the Scroller component. Adding scrollbars to layouts is not recommended, as it can mess up the layout/sizing of child components since the layout is a flex container.